# SFINAE does not work in a non-type template class

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I want to use SFINAE to select specific function to be compiled in a template class with non-type
argument, here is how i do it:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
template <bool T>
struct is_right
{
    template <class Q = std::bool_constant<T>>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, std::bool_constant<true>>::value, bool>::type check()
    {
        return true;
    }

    template <class Q = std::bool_constant<!T>>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, std::bool_constant<false>>::value, bool>::type check()
    {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    is_right<false> is_fs;
    is_right<true> is_ri;
    if(!is_fs.check() && is_ri.check()){
        std::cout << "It is right!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with g++ 8.1.0 using c++17 standard.
But the compliler gives me a error said "no matching function for call to 'is_right::check()'".

However if I just substitue the non-type template argument with a type argument, it works:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
template <class T>
struct is_right
{
    template <class Q = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, std::bool_constant<true>>::value, bool>::type check()
    {
        return true;
    }

    template <class Q = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, std::bool_constant<false>>::value, bool>::type check()
    {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    is_right<std::bool_constant<false>> is_fs;
    is_right<std::bool_constant<true>> is_ri;
    if(!is_fs.check() && is_ri.check()){
        std::cout << "It is right!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any essential difference between them?

Comment: Could you simplify to `template <bool Q = T> std::enable_if_t<Q, bool>` and `template <bool Q = T> std::enable_if_t<!Q, bool>`? Also, if you could use C++20, you would just write `bool check() requires T; bool check() requires !T;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default template parameter for the second `check` function is wrong, it should be `std::bool_constant<T>` and not `std::bool_constant<!T>`.

The call `is_fs.check()` has no matching function, because you're testing `is_same<bool_constant<false>, bool_constant<true>>` in the first overload and `is_same<bool_constant<true>, bool_constant<false>>` in the second overload.

---

Also note that right now the call `is_ri.check()` is ambiguous, because both `check` functions are valid in `is_right<true>`.